# Pytest and Unpickling Large Files

Tags: python, tornado, pickle, pytest

I have an application that, as part of its start-up, loads a very large pickled file into memory. During production, it takes about 5-10 mins to finish this start-up process. However, when I start a pytest test case that does the same thing, the start-up process never completes because it never finishes loading the pickled file into memory. What is happening?

*UPDATE:*

*I get no error. The test just never seems to run after waiting for an hour. The machine just continues to "load" the data. I've checked memory usage and it never chews up all of the available RAM. As for the processor, one of the cores hit 100%, but all other cores are doing little, if any, work. Using the `--fulltrace` option, the test seems to get stuck at the line where I am unpickling the binary file.*

Comment: does any error occur like test timeout?

Comment: No, I get no error. The test just never seems to run after waiting for an hour. The machine just continues to "load" the data. I've checked memory usage and it never chews up all of the available RAM. As for the processor, one of the cores hit 100%, but all other cores are doing little if any work. Using the `--fulltrace` option, the test seems to get stuck at the line where I am unpickling the binary file.

Comment: I would guess it has to do with the test framework. They often parallelize unit tests and collect the results in the end. Maybe this exceeds some internal timeout and the process gets killed? Is there some log output?

Comment: Martin - nothing on the console screen.